# Select search statement with full text

Tags: php, mysql, select

The way this is set up, it will pull up results for multiple words in the `$term` variable.
I want it to pull up results that only match all words inside the `$term` span between main, secondary, sub columns.

Right now if `$term` is: "Hello World" it will pull results from the database:

```
id  | main               | secondary      | sub

01  | statements         | hello world    | blah
02  | hello              | what's up?     | anything here
03  | life rocks         | worldwide web  | anything else here
04  | where in the world | she said hello | bleh
```

When what I would like is only results 01 and 04 to pull up because they include the full $term of Hello And World

Here's my code. I've tried searching on here, and in Google. But in truth I don't know what to look for. All I've found are full text searching documents, which I'm already doing here. I haven't found any to say how to pull the exact result. (The sprintf is there because I guess I need that to be able to return it in a JSON response?

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, main, secondary, sub, 
    MATCH(main, secondary, sub) AGAINST('". $term ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
    FROM list_genres 
    WHERE MATCH (main, secondary, sub) AGAINST('". $term ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 15");
```

Comment: Do you want to search with multiple terms?

Comment: I want multiple words to be searched through multiple columns. But only pull up a result if both words are found anywhere in all 3 columns, but i wasn't the full $term variable to be matched, not each word separately. .. but there will be times only 1 word will be used as well. sometimes maybe 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentece is wrong, first **sprintf()** should receive as parameters, the terms, and use %s wherever you want to add it to the sql, also for multiple words you need to add a `+` for each word.

The code should be something like this:

```
$term = '+' . str_replace(' ',' +',$term); // Remove this line if you don't want search multiple terms
$query = sprintf("SELECT id,main,secondary,sub, MATCH(main, secondary, sub) AGAINST('&s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score 
    FROM list_genres WHERE MATCH (main, secondary, sub) AGAINST('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 15", $term, $term);
```

Comment: That works. thank you. i'm a little confused as to why $term is used twice at the end. would that be once per word inside the $term, or? Thought it works as i wanted, now i'm just wanting to understand it.

Comment: I recommend you to read http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php it will help, what i did is to put %s every place where you want to add a variable ($term in this case), because there are 2 %s i put two terms.

Comment: aww.. okay, now that makes sense, i've read about the %s as a place holder, but it didn't make sense, my thinking was, why not just use a variable for you know. the variable. haha. But that makes more sense now, i'll read up on the sprintf. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, default operation for `BOOLEAN MODE` is `OR`. Adding `+` sign in front of terms you're looking for should do the trick.

```
$term = "+Hello +World"
```